# MERN app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to get mern app working on heroku. But right now even fixing of node server would be enough.

This is what i have already done.

1. Created app in heroku and push my project to it.
2. Added mLab database link. (running properly on local server)
3. put dev dependencies on the dependencies.
4. Tried running "heroku run node server.js" through heroku CLI. Then it logs as server started on port 8080.

But I cannot access the API or the web interface.
My app url = http://travelaround.herokuapp.com

**Please note** my web application was create using **create-react-app**
My Logs at heroku,

```html
2017-05-14T17:17:50.113754+00:00 heroku[api.1]: Process exited with status 0

2017-05-14T17:17:52.979224+00:00 heroku[api.1]: Starting process with command `nodemon server.js`

2017-05-14T17:17:53.538796+00:00 heroku[api.1]: State changed from starting to up

2017-05-14T17:17:55.154398+00:00 app[api.1]: [33m[nodemon] 1.11.0[39m

2017-05-14T17:17:55.156364+00:00 app[api.1]: [33m[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`[39m

2017-05-14T17:17:55.156522+00:00 app[api.1]: [33m[nodemon] watching: *.*[39m

2017-05-14T17:17:55.157062+00:00 app[api.1]: [32m[nodemon] starting `node server.js`[39m

2017-05-14T17:17:55.982045+00:00 app[api.1]: Database connection Established at mongodb://test:asd123@ds139791.mlab.com:39791/travelaround

2017-05-14T17:17:56.008148+00:00 app[api.1]: api running on port 3000

2017-05-15T14:22:19.692618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=travelaround.herokuapp.com request_id=b46a031e-db9d-4cac-93fa-ffd73f51e5f3 fwd="93.65.70.107" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

2017-05-15T14:22:20.297803+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=travelaround.herokuapp.com request_id=9ca4977c-b45e-4f3e-b98a-1034855e8c4f fwd="93.65.70.107" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

[image: Resources Tab Screen Shot]

Comment: Go into the application folder and run `heroku logs`. What's the result?

Comment: Hi @Corrado Added the Logs! :)

Comment: it seems that you have no dynos running. To fix it try running `heroku ps:scale web=1` and restart your heroku app, should work, in theory!

Comment: also, I think you might want to change the `npm start` command to simply run node, not nodemon, since it could mess with some heroku stuff, I think. Just move the nodemon command to something like `npm dev`...

Comment: Hi Corrado, Through the CLI i tried running, node server.js ; still the same result! And to what should i try changing the script ? npm run start-dev ? Tried that either!

Comment: Hm... Weird, can you send a screenshot of the `resources` tab of your app?

Comment: Also, you could just change it to whatever you want, as long as `start` is `node server.js`

Comment: Hey! Added The screen-shot you asked! Thanks a lot for trying to help. :)

Comment: Ok, cool, you just need to turn both the dynos on

Comment: Actually you might want to make them two separate heroku apps, since I think you have to pay to use more than one dyno at once

Comment: Sorry which dynos actually ??? I tried turning on qeb app and server. But didn't work. And i don't know how to access the server. Giving port number after the url doesn't actually work.

Comment: You need to have one single dyno on at a time for it to work, I suspect. Just compile your react code, that way you'll have nothing but static content for your frontend

Comment: That worked!  thanks a lot..

Comment: Cool! I'm adding it as an answer so others can benefit! Glad I could help! Accept the answer, so people see it's the correct one

Comment: Okey... Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so from the screenshot of your Heroku dashboard and error, it looks like your dynos are not running. I suggest you compile all of your react code, so you only have static content on your frontend, and then turn on the API dyno, so you can actually curl to it from your react code.